# Envio de e-mail em formato HTML com imagem de fundo e texto em cima da imagem

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, newsletter

Estou fazendo um site onde o cliente cadastra seu email e ao cadastrar ele receberá automaticamente um email com uma newsletter.

Para o envio desse email estou usando o PhpMailer

```html
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];


$Mailer = new PHPMailer();

//Define que será usado SMTP
$Mailer->IsSMTP();

//Enviar e-mail em HTML
$Mailer->isHTML(true);

//Aceitar carasteres especiais
$Mailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

//Configurações
$Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//nome do servidor
$Mailer->Host = 'servidor.com.br';
//Porta de saida de e-mail
$Mailer->Port = 30;

//Dados do e-mail de saida - autenticação
$Mailer->Username = 'meuemail@email.com.br';
$Mailer->Password = 'MinhaSenha';

//E-mail remetente (deve ser o mesmo de quem fez a autenticação)
$Mailer->From = 'meuemail@email.com.br';

//Nome do Remetente
$Mailer->FromName = utf8_decode('Agência');

//Assunto da mensagem
$Mailer->Subject = utf8_decode('Seja bem-vindo');

//Corpo da Mensagem
$Mailer->Body = utf8_decode('<div style="background-color:#e6f8fe;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://agencia306.com.br/blog-306/img/como-aproximar/1.jpg" color="#e6f8fe"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://agencia306.com.br/blog-306/img/como-aproximar/1.jpg">    <h1>Em fase de construção </h1>   </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>');

//Corpo da mensagem em texto
$Mailer->AltBody = 'conteudo do E-mail em texto';

//Destinatario
$Mailer->AddAddress($email);

if($Mailer->Send()){
    echo "<script>alert('E-mail enviado com sucesso');history.back();</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Erro no envio do e-mail: " . $Mailer->ErrorInfo . " ');history.back();</script>";
}

?>
```

O código esta funcionando tranquilo, o email chega sem problemas para a pessoa que se cadastra. Mas estou com dois problemas:

1° Problema: Mandando deste jeito, eu testo no meu email do Yahoo, o email vai sem problema. Só que o objetivo principal que é enviar uma imagem de fundo e um texto em cima dessa imagem não esta funcionando. Esta indo apenas o texto.

2° Problema: Esta indo para Span. Eu pesquisei sobre e li que usando PhpMailer isso não ia acontecer. Mas esta indo para Span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeira coisa que você precisa saber para criar e-mail marketing é que os padrões são os mais antigos do HTML, da época em que não se usava CSS para formatar as coisas. Portanto para fazer um texto com imagem de fundo você deve colocar o texto dentro de uma tabela, e utilizar o atributo **background** da tag **table**.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="http://www.seudominio.com.br/img/background_image.png">
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Inclusive para mudar fontes você precisará utilizar a tag `<font>`, para margens você precisará utilizar o padding ou spacing da propria tabela. E-mail marketing é chato de montar, mas é como devemos fazer.

Por isso muitas vezes as pessoas criam como imagem e colocam o texto num atributo alt da imagem.

Para não ser pego como spam você deve se certificar de algumas coisas. Por exemplo:

- O texto não pode palavras chave detectadas por anti spam, como:    "compre", "promoção" ou palavras similares.
- O domínio deve ter o SPF e o DKIM configurados corretamente autorizando o servidor de envio
- Você deve ter algum texto no seu e-mail, não apenas imagens
- Você deve enviar cada e-mail individualmente, sem milhares de endereços em cópia
- O servidor de envio deve ser confiável e as ferramentas de envio também, como: [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/?), [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/), [Madmimi](https://madmimi.com/)
- Você também precisa ter muita fé :)

Comment: Ola Carlos, muito obrigado. Eu estou tendo muita duvida sobre a URL do background. Pq eu coloquei desse jeito que vc falou. Usei o background do html. Só que mesmo assim não esta funcionando. Eu vi que no seu exemplo **background="background_image.png"** vc usou só o nome da imagem. Não precisa indicar o local dela??

Comment: Sim, precisa ser a url completa e hospedar a imagem em algum lugar. No caso de ferramentas como o mailchimp, você ja consegue subir pela propria ferramenta e ele hospeda esta imagem pra você.

Comment: A melhor parte da resposta: "Você também precisa ter muita fé :)" :p

Comment: kkkkkkkkkk mas é verdade...spam é um negócio chato e varia muito de servidor pra servidor que está recebendo o e-mail. Vira e mexe tem usuário reclamando que não recebeu.

Comment: Vc tem algum tutorial para utilizar esse mailchimp, por favor? Pq só colocar a url completa não esta funcionando.

Comment: Com esse mailchimp eu acrescento nos meus códigos?? Pq site esta sendo feito no código puro, sem plataforma como wordpress.

Comment: @Wess o youtube tem muitos videos explicando como mexer no mailchimp e o próprio mailchimp é bem intuitivo. Tem uma área para subir imagens e tal. Como vc está tentando?

Comment: Muito obrigado Carlos. Eu na verdade tentei de outras formas aqui sem usar o mailchimp. Mas muito obrigado, o que vc passou me ajudou muito. Eu tentei no método que vc passou usando o background do html, mas mesmo chamando toda a url, quando o email chega, a imagem de background não aparece.

Comment: Mas em questão, de aparecer em spam eu fiz os processos que você passou e graças a Deus, acredito que agora esta tranquilo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, por limitação de vários leitores de e-mail, você não consegue utilizar backgroud, já quebrei a cabeça para fazer isto funcionar porém não há como você garantir, no gmail funciona, porém no outlook não, e em vários leitores de telefone não funciona.

Sobre o spam, vai muito mais da reputação do seu servidor de e-mail e do seu endereço de e-mail. Porém estratégias de comunicação no e-mail às vezes pode resolver o seu problema, vale investir um tempo nestas questões de e-mail.

Comment: sugiro que remova sua resposta e á adicione como comentário, uma vez que a mesma não fornece uma solução para a questão na qual faz referência.